# Prove $\forall B, A\subset B \land A$ and $B$ are disjoint $\implies A=\emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

*Proof.*

Let $a\in A$. Inasmuch as $A\subset B$  we have $$\forall a\in A(a\in B)$$Now, assuming $A$ and $B$ are disjoint there is no $x$ such that $x\notin A \vee x\notin B$. So, in particular $$\forall a\in A\left(a\notin B\right)$$ In short, our assumptions led us to an absurdity such as $a\in B$ and $a\notin B$ providing $a\in A$, from which we can say $a\in \emptyset$. And since $\forall x\in \emptyset(x\in A)$ is trivial we've stablished $A=\emptyset$.

Is my attempt of a proof alright?

Comment: Correct, but wordy. What about: $A \subset A \cap B = \emptyset$ (because $A$ and $B$ are disjoint), so $A = \emptyset$.

Comment: Hahaha. You're right, cheers!